# Footer doesn't stay at the bottom

Tags: xml, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I'm trying to create an simple planning app on Sap Web IDE and I have this problem that the footer doesn't stay at the bottom.

**The index:**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://procensus.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <title>Procensus</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-preload="async"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" 
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"zapp_rej_absence": "./", "sap.ui.demo.mock": "mockdata"}'>
    </script>

    <!-- Application launch configuration -->
    <script>

        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
        new sap.m.Shell({
            app: new sap.m.App({
                pages: [
                    new sap.m.Page({
                        title: "Procensus Planning Calender",
                        enableScrolling: true,
                        content: [ new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                            name: "zapp_rej_absence"
                        })]
                    })]
            })
        }).placeAt("content");
    });

    </script>
</head>

<!-- UI Content -->
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content" role="application">
</body>
```

**The XML:**

```
<mvc:View 
controllerName="zapp_rej_absence.controller.Main" 
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:commons="sap.ui.commons"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page
    title="{i18n>loginTitle}"
    showHeader="true">
    <content>

        <VBox alignItems="Center" class="sapUiLargeMarginTop">
            <Panel backgroundDesign="Solid"> 
                <Image width="auto" height="10em" id="__image1" src="images/logo/Logo_iQos.jpg" 
                    class="sapUiSmallMargin"/>
                <VBox alignItems="Center" >
                    <Input id="user" type="Text" placeholder="{i18n>userName}"/>
                    <Input id="pass" type="Password" placeholder="{i18n>password}" />
        <Button class="sapUiSmallMarginTop" text="Login" width="17em" type="Emphasized" press="_logIn" submit="_logIn" />   
                </VBox>

            </Panel>
        </VBox>

    </content>
    <footer>
        <Bar>
            <contentLeft>
                <Text text="{version>/version} {version>/pool}" /> <!-- major.minot.micro - major keep at 1 until major re-release , minor - increment on new feature ; micro - increment on bug fix or minor feature change -->   
            </contentLeft>
        </Bar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

[Final Result - Mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4d1A.jpg)

[Result from Loki code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLEIz.jpg)

*Note: The calendar needs to be (as far as I know) inside a Panel tag so it doesn't disappear. And since the footer doesn't exist on the Panel tag, I've created a Page tag after closing the Panel one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the changes. You need to bind your values in the view what you have from your model and i8nproperties. I had no values and i8nproperties so left them blank but i created a skeleton if it is correct you may refer it.

Check the below three images: 1) index.html 2) view.xml 3)output
[image: index.html]

[image: View1.view.xml]

[image: output]

Comment: i had to delete the image of the result to add the index one

Comment: nope, its different, but it stays at the top. And besides that the calendar has disappeared :\

Comment: @TheAndréGomes okay. I will provide you with the code that makes you change the index.html a littlebit and your view.xml a little bit. Give me some time

Comment: @TheAndréGomes check now I edited the answer. I am also new to this so just trying out different things.

Comment: Did you use CSS for the footer?

Comment: @TheAndréGomes no I didnot. No css, no model, no i8nproperties file. I just created the application from template and made changes to index.html and View1.view.xml.

Is this  output you needed ?

Comment: this is extremely weird then.... I copied your code, im sure i copied right, but this time doesn't appear anything :/

Comment: I will investigate a little bit more with my fellow colleagues and i'll tell you something as soon as possible.Oooh and yes this is exactly the output i need. And thanks a lot for your help so far @loki :)

Comment: @TheAndréGomes While copying did you check the namespace of the Controller. In the sap.init() (index.html) I named it as demoStack but you need to name it different. Try to make your index.html exact as mine only you need to change the name property in Component Container constructor and also the data-sap-ui-resources property in script. Also check the console what error it gives you.

Comment: It works!!! It finally works!!! Thank you a lot @loki for your pacience and for your help :)

Comment: @TheAndréGomes   Congrats. :) Did the solution I provided helped ? If yes you can accept the answer if no let me know what different thing had to be done to make it work so that it would be learning for me too.

Comment: @TheAndréGomes  hey no problem happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xml-structure is wrong. It should work if you do it like this:

```
<mvc:View .......
<Page title="Your Title">
<content>
    <!-- your panel with calender here -->
</content>
<footer>
    <!-- your footer code here -->
</footer>

</Page>

</mvc:View>
```

A good code example is here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Page/code

and you can see how it looks like here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Page/code

Comment: after i organized the code the calendar as disappeared (as I said above, but thanks for your help :)

Comment: oh and i forgot to mencion it earlier. I'm using that exact same examples you gave me